# Where do I start with Facebook app development with VS2012 and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-apps

I'm an asp.net mvc/C# software developer, but I have no experience in Facebook development. I have no idea where to begin when it comes to develop a facebook app.

I have litlle bit google but cannot get greater help but just found one link

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update/facebook-application-template-tutorial

Where do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same place you would with any other new technology, [their documentation](http://csharpsdk.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Facebook app template in Visual Studio 2012 (with the latest update 2012.2).

Get started with the link you provided:
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update/facebook-application-template-tutorial, it will help you get moving quickly.